# Http error 500 :Internal Server error when trying to download .jad file from some particular location on server in Blackberry browser

Tags: http, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I uploaded a blackberry app(.cod & .jad file) in some paricular location on server.Now when I am trying to downlaod the .jad file from my blackberry browser , Its giving **HTTP error 500:Internal Server Error** . Howerver It was working fine a few days ago and still downloadable through PC browser but the problem coming when I am trying to download it from Blackberry browser. 
Can anyone explain me why this error is coming and how it can be removed....?

Comment: What do server logs say?

Comment: how can i check the server log  ?

Comment: this is not a programming question